# How to use Customize your Queries in JPA with Query Methods (spring boot)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to retrieve a specific value from the database based on a criteria without using the query method in Spring JPA.
they query desired is

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Co2 WHERE Co2.room = ?1 order by co2.id desc
```

which can be used in a normal native query annotation like so:

```
public interface Co2Respository extends CrudRepository<Co2, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Co2 WHERE Co2.room = ?1 order by co2.id desc",
    nativeQuery = true)
    Co2 findLastInsertedValueForRoom(int id);
}
```

the question is how to achieve the same using the custom query method in Spring JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question,
the equivalent custom method for the query mentioned above is:

```
Co2 findTopByRoomOrderByIdDesc(Room room);
```